# Portainer not loading properly

Tags: docker, portainer

I have downloaded the Portainer image and created the container in the Docker manager node, by using the below command.

```
docker run -d -p 61010:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock portainer/portainer
```

But after some time the container is getting excited. Also when I access the Portainer with the above port it's just saying Portainer loading and nothing is happening. PFB the logs for the Portainer

```
2019/10/16 16:20:58 server: Reverse tunnelling enabled
2019/10/16 16:20:58 server: Fingerprint 43:68:57:37:e4:3f:f7:98:bd:52:13:39:c6:6d:24:c9
2019/10/16 16:20:58 server: Listening on 0.0.0.0:8000...
2019/10/16 16:20:58 Starting Portainer 1.22.1 on :9000
2019/10/16 16:20:58 [DEBUG] [chisel, monitoring] [check_interval_seconds: 10.000000] [message: 
starting tunnel management process]
2019/10/16 16:25:58 No administrator account was created after 5 min. Shutting down the Portainer 
instance for security reasons.
2019/10/16 16:30:12 Templates already registered inside the database. Skipping template import.
2019/10/16 16:30:12 server: Reverse tunnelling enabled
2019/10/16 16:30:12 server: Fingerprint 43:68:57:37:e4:3f:f7:98:bd:52:13:39:c6:6d:24:c9
2019/10/16 16:30:12 server: Listening on 0.0.0.0:8000...
2019/10/16 16:30:12 Starting Portainer 1.22.1 on :9000
2019/10/16 16:30:12 [DEBUG] [chisel, monitoring] [check_interval_seconds: 10.000000] [message: 
starting tunnel management process]
2019/10/16 16:35:12 No administrator account was created after 5 min. Shutting down the Portainer 
instance for security reasons.
```

I am not sure whether the Porainer is running on 61010. Also, do i need to install Agent for this to work Please help to resolve this.

Comment: you can try to access Portainer via the browser url `localhost:61010`

Answer (score 4):

Follow the [docs](https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment.html) and it should work:

> Quick start If you are running Linux, deploying Portainer is as simple
>   as:

```
$ docker volume create portainer_data 
$ docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 --name portainer --restart always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer
```

Voilà, you can now use Portainer by accessing the

> port 9000 on the server where Portainer is running.

Once you access the `localhost:9000` in the browser, you will be required to created admin account, afterwards you will see the Portainer ui

Comment: i am using a actual linux server in my working place. so i dont have connectivity for port 9000. so i try mapping it to port 61010. after creating the container when i access it through the server IP and port it is jst saying loading Portainer i dont get an option to create the Admin account. After some time the container get exited.  Also is  it a must i create a data volume.